# Unit testing AngularJS factory having method making http requests

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, gulp, karma-jasmine

I am unit testing following framework with karma and jasmine.

```
 var userApiFactory = (function ($http, $log, $q, appConfig) {
 apiFactory.logoutUser = function () {
    return $http.get(urlBase + "Auth/Logout");
};
}
```

I am 100% sure that API that actually gets hit through above `$http` request is working fine and returns a promise containing some JSON data.

I have not mocked factory because all of them contains methods making HTTP requests and by testing this factory I just have to test that all methods are being called with correct parameters and those methods are subsequently making correct http requests with correct parameters.

Hence, I have rather taken an instance of original factory and referenced it. I have also created fake `httpBackEnd` so that actual APIs are not hit rather a fake promise with required data is being returned. My unit test looks like this:

```
describe('unitTesting', function () {

var jsonData = {
    "logoutSucess": true
}

beforeEach(angular.mock.module('sampleApp'));

//Mocking authService
beforeEach(angular.mock.module(function($provide){

    $provide.constant('APP_CONFIG', {
        apiBaseUrl: "https://some.url.com"
    })
}));

var mock_appconfig, httpBackend, mockUserApiFactory;

beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function(APP_CONFIG, $httpBackend, userApiFactory, $q){
    mock_appconfig = APP_CONFIG;
    httpBackend = $httpBackend;
    mockUserApiFactory = userApiFactory;
    var defer = $q.defer();
    defer.resolve(jsonData);
    httpBackend.when("GET",mock_appconfig.apiBaseUrl+"Auth/Logout").respond(defer.promise);
}));

it('mockUserApiFactory has log out method working', function(){
   spyOn(mockUserApiFactory, "logoutUser");
    var rcvd_data;
    var res = mockUserApiFactory.logoutUser();
    res.then(function(data){
           rcvd_data = data;
        })
    expect(mockUserApiFactory.logoutUser).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(rcvd_data).toEqual(jsonData);
})
});
```

I am getting error: `Cannot read property then of undefined`.

Comment: Your `apiBaseUrl` has no trailing slash and you concatenate the string `Auth/Logout` but you basically want `/Auth/Logout`

Comment: I changed 'Auth/Logout' to '/AuthLogout', still not working. Pls help

Comment: What you're doing makes no sense: you're mocking the method that you're testing. So your test doesn't execute the real logoutUser() function. It executes the mock one, doing nothing. The principle of mocking is: to test A, which depends on B, you mock B. What you're doing is mock A when testing A.